# Express use function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The below code not functioning as expected

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('first text');
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('secondText');
  res.end()
}).listen(3000)
```

`app.use([path,] function [, function...])`
Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path. If path is not specified, it defaults to `'/'` in express documentation but I can't run the second function, not sure why. When I try `localhost:3000` in Firefox I receive `Cannot GET /`

This code is working, but previously it wasn't working:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("one");
  next();
})
.use(function(req,res,next){    
    console.log("second");
    res.end()
})
.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because of the missing `.`?

```
 var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('first text');
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('secondText');
}).listen(3000) //Was missing a period
```

Comment: no, i forgot add dot in post only, but if i add dot it still don't working

Comment: Why would one downvote this? Valid answer at the Time.